# A NameError doing a Product class in views.py at product/1/new

Tags: python, django

I am doing a Product application for fun, to which I got an error.

The error says that redirect is not defined at line 29 in my views.py file. Here is my views.py file
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .forms import NewProductForm
from .models import Product

```
# Create your views here.

def home(request):

    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'products': products})

def product_topics(request, pk):

    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'topics.html', {'product': product})

def new_product(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    user = User.objects.first()
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        form = NewProductForm(request.POST)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            product = form.save(commit = False)
            product.starter = user
            product.save()

            return redirect('product_topics',pk=product.pk)
    else:
        form = NewProductForm()
    return render(request, 'new_product.html', {'product': product, 'form': form})
```

Here's my urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from inventories import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.product_topics, name='product_topics'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<pk>\d+)/new/$', views.new_product, name='new_product'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And here's the form that I used to create a new product

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block title %}Start a New Topic{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Products</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'product_topics' product.pk %}">{{ product.name }}</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">New topic</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.label_tag }}

        {% render_field field class="form-control" %}

        {% if field.help_text %}
          <small class="form-text text-muted">
            {{ field.help_text }}
          </small>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

What does this error mean, and can you show me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't imported the redirect function. Add this to your views

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
```